# Global Hotkey for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, hotkeys, global-hotkey

Is there a way to add hotkeys (such as the media buttons) for the webbrowser?

This would need to cause a javascript event.

I except a firefox extension is required and i am ok if the solution requires greasemonkey as well (i seen growl use them both for javascript interaction. But thats javascript->pc not the other way around)

-edit- is this not possible ATM?

Comment: You mean, independently from the page the user is on?

Comment: @Pekka: independently would be nice. But if it wasnt i wouldnt mind.

Comment: well, you can define hotkeys inside a page e.g. using the jQuery  hotkeys plugin, but they will cease to work once you leave the page. Is that acceptable?

Comment: +1 cause it helped. I googled and found test-static-08 which shows me i can use play/pause/etc. Now once some plugin allows firefox to see those keys i'll be all set

Comment: vlc has an option to add global hotkeys irrespective of what is focused, combine that with the fact that you can stream video/audio from youtube and such and that might work for a few options, to act as 'global "media buttons"'.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox supports something called an `AppCommand` event. On Windows and Linux, only 7 commands are supported: Back, Forward, Reload, Stop, Search, Bookmarks and Home.

To implement extra commands, supported would have to be added to `widget/src/windows/nsWindow.cpp` and `widget/src/gtk2/nsWindow.cpp` to generate those additional types of AppCommand event. These events could then be intercepted by an extension to perform custom actions.

On Android, a different set of events are supported: Clear, VolumeUp, VolumeDown, Menu, Search. I don't know whether these events are used by Fennec.

For completeness, OS/2 builds of Firefox support Back, Forward, Reload and Stop.